# centos streaming server for Video on demand

Tags: linux, centos, video

I'm using centos 5.4 with vlc streaming server i can do the streaming on http,https but when i wanted to rtsp and rtp which i wanted to config for all the wifi phone. From the server it will redirect to  wifi router.

Comment: You need to seriously rework this question to make it clearer - why is WiFi relevant?, what client application (OS and application) are you having problems with? What problems are those?

Comment: I want streaming  on LAN but using WiFi route we work 24/7 so for entertainment we putting video streaming server which have video song, films. So every one don't have laptop but cellphone with wifi everyone having so we are looking to streaming on wifi so they can use VOD (video on demanad) from the list which will have on our wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rajat,

I am assuming you are asking about streaming rtsp as a format your phone can connect to, in addition to a (different/separate) format your desktop clients currently have working? I could be wrong, but it sounds like wifi has nothing to do with the question. If the actual problem is only happening when clients are on wifi rather then a wired connection, that will open up a whole new world of possibilities rather then just the actual stream itself.

Additional clarification would go a long way in us helping you with your issue. Also be sure to confirm that everyone on their phone is actually connecting through internal wifi (same as laptop users) and not a cellular connection like 3g/edge/etc (coming in from the outside world).

If you are asking about vlc and rtsp/rtp streaming, start here: http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch04.html#id311704